# Delphi non-rtti inspector

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have some virtual controls which is a part of a designer system i have made. They mimic delphi's own components, except that they are fully owner-drawn. The problem I am faced with is that, since my property system is somewhat different from ordinary Delphi - I cant use an RTTI inspector to edit the properties.

Does anyone know about a inspector that looks and acts like the normal delphi inspector, but that allows me to define the properties by code?

And if possible, one which allows me to define enums:

```
with edInspector.Items.add('align') do
Begin
  Options.add('alLeft',ftord(TMyAlign.azLeft));
  Options.add('alTop',ord(TMyAlign.azTop));
  Options.add('alRight',ord(TMyAlign.azRight));
  Options.add('alBottom',ord(TMyAlign.azBottom));
  Options.add('alClient',ord(TMyAlign.azClient));
end;
```

and complex types:

```
with edInspector.Items.add('font') do
Begin
  subitems.add('name',dtString).value:=def_FontName;
  subitems.add('size',dtInteger).value:=def_fontSize;
  subitems.add('color',dtColor).Value:=def_fontColor;
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my property system is somewhat different from ordinary Delphi"? Are you aware of the difference between public and published properties?

Comment: He he, yes. Im polling properties from an external system, which means they are stored in name/value pairs in custom objects. So they are not visible from normal RTTI, i have to get/set them manually

Comment: Ok, if all that is different is your persistence mechanism, use published properties declared with "stored False" and the build in object inspector for design time editing. If you need help with your persistence mechanism (i.e. converting text to values you can assign to normally typed properties), take a look at how TReader and TFiler does the job.

Comment: I cant define them in a normal delphi object, because they are not known at designtime, but polled from a server at runtime. It can be any structure.

Comment: In such case, what does the RTTI inspector have to do with your question? Do you want a GUI component that acts like the design time IDE object inspector, but at run time?

Comment: Have you looked at [JVCL TjvInspector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/) ? A summary and example usage can be found here at [NeuglsWorkStudio](http://www.neugls.info/?tag=jvcl).

Comment: @HenrickHellström: if you check the title, it says "NON-rtti"

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden: The reason I ask is just because it seems to me you are trying to reinvent the wheel, namely: You are either attempting to implement your own RTTI or implement your own data access object framework, or you are just asking for how to use TListView for editing.

Comment: A very old version of DeveloperExpress's inspector component allowed you to add properties to a vertical list which had editors for the different datatypes. Thats basically what i want, but the latest devex package is to evolved for this and only deals with RTTI. Im not looking for a db solution. Think more in terms of ajax arrays of data that a user can alter. So its not complex, but i want to look like like the inspector in delphi.

Comment: @JonLennartAasenden you should add your comment to question as reason why

Answer (score 2):

Give **Inspex** a try. It's pretty cool.

http://www.raize.com/DevTools/Inspex/Default.asp

You can add properties dynamically, and you'll get property editors for most of the common types.

It can behave pretty much like the Delphi object inspector (it lets you edit sets, if you add multiple objects, it detects which properties are the same, and hides the others, and it does the same for property values).

It shows properties in a tree-like structure if there are multiple levels.
You can easily populate it by adding any TObject, via a string, or by adding the properties one by one.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks good, but its not free. I should have stated that i would like a free alternative.

Answer (score 0):

With [Delphi Runtime Inspector](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtinspector/), you will be able to see object information at run-time.

Comment: You should certainly adapt it to comply with your requirement.

Comment: I dont want runtime information. I want to edit my own structures that i define by code at runtime. But i dont want to inspect "real" objects.